# Adding a new layout for genesis

Tags: theme-development, functions, genesis-theme-framework

I have added a new layout for the genesis framework called "modalwindow".
This layout should only display the content because it is a modal window loading page content (I don't want any of the header, sidebars, footers, menus or anything else displayed, just the content from that page).

What do I add for it to only display the content of that page with nothing else? ie: code to remove header, sidebars, footers, menus, etc.
At the moment I have selected the "modalwindow" layout for the page in WP admin- now need to strip everything from the content.

Code:

```
// from "/themes/genesis/lib/structure/layout.php"

<?php
/**
 * Controls layout structure.
 *
 * @package Genesis
 */

add_filter( 'content_width', 'genesis_content_width', 10, 3 );
/**
 * This function filters the content width based on the user selected layout.
 *
 * @since 1.6
 */
function genesis_content_width( $default, $small, $large ) {

    switch ( genesis_site_layout() ) {
        case 'full-width-content':
            $width = $large;
            break;
        case 'content-sidebar-sidebar':
        case 'sidebar-content-sidebar':
        case 'sidebar-sidebar-content':
            $width = $small;
            break;
        default:
            $width = $default;
    }

    return $width;

}

add_filter('body_class', 'genesis_custom_body_class', 15);
/**
 * This function/filter adds custom body class(es) to the
 * body class array. It accepts values from a per-post/page
 * custom field, and only outputs when viewing singular page.
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
function genesis_custom_body_class( $classes ) {

    $new_class = is_singular() ? genesis_get_custom_field( '_genesis_custom_body_class' ) : null;

    if ( $new_class ) $classes[] = esc_attr( sanitize_html_class( $new_class ) );

    return $classes;

}

add_action('genesis_meta', 'genesis_load_stylesheet');
/**
 * This function loads the stylesheet.
 * If a child theme is active, it loads the child theme's stylesheet,
 * otherwise, it loads the Genesis stylesheet.
 *
 */
function genesis_load_stylesheet() {

    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url').'" type="text/css" media="screen" />'."\n";

}

add_filter('body_class', 'genesis_header_body_classes');
/**
 * This function/filter adds new classes to the <body>
 * so that we can use psuedo-variables in our CSS file,
 * which helps us achieve multiple header layouts with minimal code
 *
 * @since 0.2.2
 */
function genesis_header_body_classes($classes) {

    // add header classes to $classes array
    if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'header-right' ) )
        $classes[] = 'header-full-width';

    if ( 'image' == genesis_get_option('blog_title') || 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() )
        $classes[] = 'header-image';

    // return filtered $classes
    return $classes;

}

add_filter('body_class', 'genesis_layout_body_classes');
/**
 * This function/filter adds new classes to the <body>
 * so that we can use psuedo-variables in our CSS file,
 * which helps us achieve multiple site layouts with minimal code
 *
 * @since 0.2.2
 */
function genesis_layout_body_classes($classes) {

    // get the layout
    $site_layout = genesis_site_layout();

    // add new class to $classes array
    if ( $site_layout ) $classes[] = $site_layout;

    // return filtered $classes
    return $classes;
}

add_action('genesis_after_content', 'genesis_get_sidebar');
/**
 * This function outputs the sidebar.php file
 * if specified in theme options or in-post options
 *
 * @since 0.2
 */
function genesis_get_sidebar() {

    // get the layout
    $site_layout = genesis_site_layout();

    // don't load sidebar on pages that don't need it
    if ( $site_layout == 'full-width-content' ||
        $site_layout == 'modalwindow' ) return;

    // output the primary sidebar
    get_sidebar();
}

add_action('genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap', 'genesis_get_sidebar_alt');
/**
 * This function outputs the sidebar_alt.php file
 * if specified in theme options or in-post options
 *
 * @since 0.2
 */
function genesis_get_sidebar_alt() {

    // get the layout
    $site_layout = genesis_site_layout();

    // don't load sidebar-alt on pages that don't need it
    if ( $site_layout == 'content-sidebar' ||
        $site_layout == 'sidebar-content' ||
        $site_layout == 'full-width-content' ||
        $site_layout == 'modalwindow' ) return;

    // output the alternate sidebar
    get_sidebar('alt');

}
```

Code:

```
// from "/themes/genesis/lib/functions/layout.php"

<?php
/**
 * Register default Genesis layouts.
 *
 * @package Genesis
 */

add_action('genesis_init', 'genesis_create_initial_layouts', 0);
/**
 * Creates the initial layouts when the 'init' action is fired
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
function genesis_create_initial_layouts() {

    genesis_register_layout( 'content-sidebar', array(
        'label' => __('Content-Sidebar', 'genesis'),
        'img' => GENESIS_ADMIN_IMAGES_URL . '/layouts/cs.gif',
        'default' => true
    ) );

    genesis_register_layout( 'sidebar-content', array(
        'label' => __('Sidebar-Content', 'genesis'),
        'img' => GENESIS_ADMIN_IMAGES_URL . '/layouts/sc.gif'
    ) );

    genesis_register_layout( 'content-sidebar-sidebar', array(
        'label' => __('Content-Sidebar-Sidebar', 'genesis'),
        'img' => GENESIS_ADMIN_IMAGES_URL . '/layouts/css.gif'
    ) );

    genesis_register_layout( 'sidebar-sidebar-content', array(
        'label' => __('Sidebar-Sidebar-Content', 'genesis'),
        'img' => GENESIS_ADMIN_IMAGES_URL . '/layouts/ssc.gif'
    ) );

    genesis_register_layout( 'sidebar-content-sidebar', array(
        'label' => __('Sidebar-Content-Sidebar', 'genesis'),
        'img' => GENESIS_ADMIN_IMAGES_URL . '/layouts/scs.gif'
    ) );

    genesis_register_layout( 'full-width-content', array(
        'label' => __('Full Width Content', 'genesis'),
        'img' => GENESIS_ADMIN_IMAGES_URL . '/layouts/c.gif',
    ) );

    genesis_register_layout( 'modalwindow', array(
        'label' => __('Sizing Guide Layout', 'genesis'),
        'img' => CHILD_URL . '/images/stcsb.gif',
    ) );
}

/**
 * This function registers new layouts by modifying the global
 * $_genesis_layouts variable.
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
function genesis_register_layout( $id = '', $args = array() ) {

    global $_genesis_layouts;

    if ( !is_array( $_genesis_layouts ) )
        $_genesis_layouts = array();

    // Don't allow empty $id, or double registrations
    if ( !$id || isset( $_genesis_layouts[$id] ) )
        return false;

    $defaults = array(
        'label' => __( 'No Label Selected', 'genesis' ),
        'img' => GENESIS_ADMIN_IMAGES_URL . '/layouts/none.gif',
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    $_genesis_layouts[$id] = $args;

    return $args;

}

/**
 * This function allows a user to identify a layout as being the default
 * layout on a new install, as well as serve as the fallback layout.
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
function genesis_set_default_layout( $id = '' ) {

    global $_genesis_layouts;

    if ( !is_array( $_genesis_layouts ) )
        $_genesis_layouts = array();

    // Don't allow empty $id, or double registrations
    if ( !$id || !isset( $_genesis_layouts[$id] ) )
        return false;

    // remove default flag for all other layouts
    foreach ( (array)$_genesis_layouts as $key => $value ) {
        if ( isset( $_genesis_layouts[$key]['default'] ) ) {
            unset( $_genesis_layouts[$key]['default'] );
        }
    }

    $_genesis_layouts[$id]['default'] = true;

    return $id;

}

/**
 * This function unregisters layouts by modifying the global
 * $_genesis_layouts variable.
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
function genesis_unregister_layout( $id = '' ) {

    global $_genesis_layouts;

    if ( !$id || !isset( $_genesis_layouts[$id] ) )
        return false;

    unset( $_genesis_layouts[$id] );

    return true;

}

/**
 * This function returns all registered Genesis Layouts
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
function genesis_get_layouts() {

    global $_genesis_layouts;

    if ( !is_array( $_genesis_layouts ) )
        $_genesis_layouts = array();

    return $_genesis_layouts;

}

/**
 * This function returns the data from a single layout,
 * specified by the $id passed to it.
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
function genesis_get_layout( $id ) {

    $layouts = genesis_get_layouts();

    if ( !$id || !isset( $layouts[$id] ) )
        return;

    return $layouts[$id];

}

/**
 * This function returns the layout that is set to default.
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
function genesis_get_default_layout() {

    global $_genesis_layouts;

    $default = '';

    foreach ( (array)$_genesis_layouts as $key => $value ) {
        if ( isset( $value['default'] ) && $value['default'] ) {
            $default = $key; break;
        }
    }

    // return default layout, if exists
    if ( $default ) {
        return $default;
    }

    return 'nolayout';

}

/**
 * This function checks both the custom field and
 * the theme option to find the user-selected site
 * layout, and returns it.
 *
 * @since 0.2.2
 */
function genesis_site_layout() {

    // If viewing a singular page/post
    if ( is_singular() ) {

        $custom_field = genesis_get_custom_field( '_genesis_layout' );
        $site_layout = $custom_field ? $custom_field : genesis_get_option( 'site_layout' );

    }

    // If viewing a taxonomy archive
    elseif ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax() ) {
        global $wp_query;

        $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

        $site_layout = $term && isset( $term->meta['layout'] ) && $term->meta['layout'] ? $term->meta['layout'] : genesis_get_option( 'site_layout' );

    }

    // If viewing an author archive
    elseif( is_author() ) {

        $site_layout = get_the_author_meta( 'layout', (int)get_query_var('author') ) ? get_the_author_meta( 'layout', (int)get_query_var('author') ) : genesis_get_option('site_layout');

    }

    // else pull the theme option
    else {

        $site_layout = genesis_get_option( 'site_layout' );

    }

    // Use default layout as a fallback, if necessary
    if ( !genesis_get_layout( $site_layout ) ) {
        $site_layout = genesis_get_default_layout();
    }

    return esc_attr( apply_filters( 'genesis_site_layout', $site_layout ) );

}

/**
 * A helper function that outputs the form elements necessary to select a layout.
 *
 * You must manually wrap this in an HTML element with the class of 'genesis-layout-selector'
 * in order for the CSS and Javascript to apply properly.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
function genesis_layout_selector( $args = array() ) {

    /** Merge defaults with user args */
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
        'name'     => '',
        'selected' => '',
        'echo'     => true
    ) );

    $output = '';

    foreach ( genesis_get_layouts() as $id => $data ) {

        $class = $id == $args['selected'] ? 'selected' : '';

        $output .= sprintf( '<label title="%1$s" class="box %2$s"><img src="%3$s" alt="%1$s" /><br /> <input type="radio" name="%4$s" id="%5$s" value="%5$s" %6$s /></label>',
                esc_attr( $data['label'] ),
                esc_attr( $class ),
                esc_url( $data['img'] ),
                esc_attr( $args['name'] ),
                esc_attr( $id ),
                checked( $id, $args['selected'], false )
        );

    }

    /** Echo or Return output */
    if ( $args['echo'] )
        echo $output;
    else
        return $output;

}

/**
* A helper function to do the logic, and potentially echo/return a structural wrap div.
*
* @since 1.6
*/
function genesis_structural_wrap( $context = '', $output = '<div class="wrap">', $echo = true ) {

    $genesis_structural_wraps = get_theme_support( 'genesis-structural-wraps' );

    if ( ! in_array( $context, (array) $genesis_structural_wraps[0] ) )
        return '';

    switch( $output ) {
        case 'open':
            $output = '<div class="wrap">';
            break;
        case 'close':
            $output = '</div><!-- end .wrap -->';
            break;
    }

    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;
    else
        return $output;

}

/**
 * Helper function for returning layout key 'content-sidebar'.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
function __genesis_return_content_sidebar() {
    return 'content-sidebar';
}

/**
 * Helper function for returning layout key 'sidebar-content'.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
function __genesis_return_sidebar_content() {
    return 'sidebar-content';
}

/**
 * Helper function for returning layout key 'content-sidebar-sidebar'.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
function __genesis_return_content_sidebar_sidebar() {
    return 'content-sidebar-sidebar';
}

/**
 * Helper function for returning layout key 'sidebar-sidebar-content'.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
function __genesis_return_sidebar_sidebar_content() {
    return 'sidebar-sidebar-content';
}

/**
 * Helper function for returning layout key 'sidebar-content-sidebar'.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
function __genesis_return_sidebar_content_sidebar() {
    return 'sidebar-content-sidebar';
}

/**
 * Helper function for returning layout key 'full-width-content'.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
function __genesis_return_full_width_content() {
    return 'full-width-content';
}

/**
 * Helper function for returning layout key 'modalwindow'.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
function __genesis_return_modalwindow_content() {
    return 'modalwindow';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted answering my own question with the following code:

```
// Added to layout.php in /genesis/lib/structure.php

add_action('genesis_before', 'modalwindow_layout_logic');

    function modalwindow_layout_logic() {

        $site_layout = genesis_site_layout();

        if ( $site_layout == 'modalwindow' ) {
            // Remove default genesis sidebars
            remove_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'genesis_get_sidebar' );
            remove_action( 'genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap', 'genesis_get_sidebar_alt');
            remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );  
            remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );  
            // Remove layout specific sidebars
            remove_action('genesis_before_header', 'genesis_do_nav');
            remove_action('genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_subnav');
            remove_action('genesis_header', 'genesis_do_nav');
            remove_action('genesis_footer','themedy_footer_menu');
            remove_action('genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs'); // Remove Breadcrumbs by default
            remove_action('genesis_after_header','themedy_secondary_area');
        }
    }
```

There seems to be more that needs removing- any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just ask this on the Genesis support forums?  I thought they provided pretty good support and had a large community of developers over there.